# Sending/receiving C UDP packets failing silently (SVR 3.2 with TLI)

Tags: c, unix, networking

I am trying to write a UDP server and client on AT&T UNIX SVR 3.2 using the TLI network API. The server is working so far as it shows up on `netstat -a -n` with a local interface of 127.0.0.1:4000. When I send user data from another program with `t_sndudata()`, no error code is returned but the packet doesn't appear from the listener. Can anyone identify a coding error responsible for this problem?

**listen.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <tiuser.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>

main() {
        int fd;
        int flags;

        struct t_bind *bind;
        struct t_unitdata *ud;
        struct t_uderr *uderr;
        char *addr;
        struct sockaddr_in myaddr;

        extern int t_errno;

        if ((fd = t_open("/dev/udp", O_RDWR, NULL)) < 0) {
                t_error("unable to open UDP provider");
                exit(1);
        }

        if ((bind = (struct t_bind *)t_alloc(fd, T_BIND, T_ADDR)) == NULL) {
                t_error("t_alloc of t_bind structure failed");
                exit(2);
        }

        memset((void *)&myaddr, 0, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
        myaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
        myaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(0x7f000001);
        myaddr.sin_port = htons(4000);
        memcpy(bind->addr.buf, &myaddr, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));

        bind->qlen = 1;
        bind->addr.len = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);

        if (t_bind(fd, bind, bind) < 0) {
                t_error("t_bind failed");
                exit(3);
        }

        printf("Listening!\n");

        if ((ud = (struct t_unitdata *)t_alloc(fd, T_UNITDATA, T_ALL)) == NULL) {
                t_error("t_alloc of t_unitdata structure failed");
                exit(5);
        }

        if ((uderr = (struct t_uderr *)t_alloc(fd, T_UDERROR, T_ALL)) == NULL) {
                t_error("t_alloc of t_uderr structure failed");
                exit(6);
        }

        while (1) {
                if (t_rcvudata(fd, ud, &flags) < 0) {
                        char buffer[256];
                        strncpy(buffer, ud->udata.buf, ud->udata.len);
                        printf("Receive: %s\n", buffer);
                }
                printf("Loop");
        }

}
```

**send.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <tiuser.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>

main(argc, argv)
int argc;
char **argv;
{
        int fd;
        int flags;

        struct t_bind *bind;
        struct t_unitdata *ud;
        struct t_uderr *uderr;
        char *addr;
        struct sockaddr_in myaddr;
        struct sockaddr_in srvaddr;

        extern int t_errno;

        if ((fd = t_open("/dev/udp", O_RDWR, NULL)) < 0) {
                t_error("unable to open UDP provider");
                exit(1);
        }

        if ((bind = (struct t_bind *)t_alloc(fd, T_BIND, T_ADDR)) == NULL) {
                t_error("t_alloc of t_bind structure failed");
                exit(2);
        }

        memset((void *)&myaddr, 0, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
        myaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
        myaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(0x7f000001);
        myaddr.sin_port = htons(4001);
        memcpy(bind->addr.buf, &myaddr, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));

        bind->qlen = 0;
        bind->addr.len = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);

        if (t_bind(fd, bind, bind) < 0) {
                t_error("t_bind failed");
                exit(3);
        }

        printf("Sending: %s\n", argv[1]);

        if ((ud = (struct t_unitdata *)t_alloc(fd, T_UNITDATA, T_ALL)) == NULL) {
                t_error("t_alloc of t_unitdata structure failed");
                exit(5);
        }

        memset((void *)&srvaddr, 0, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
        srvaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
        srvaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(0x7f000001);
        srvaddr.sin_port = htons(4000);
        memcpy(ud->addr.buf, &srvaddr, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
        ud->addr.len = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
        printf("The udata buf can hold %d bytes\n", ud->udata.maxlen);
        strcpy(ud->udata.buf, argv[1]);
        ud->udata.len = strlen(argv[1]);
        printf("I have set up %d bytes and it contains %s\n", ud->udata.len, ud->udata.buf);
        ud->opt.len = 0;

        printf("Calling t_sndudata()...\n");
        if (t_sndudata(fd, ud) < 0) {
                t_error("t_sndudata failed");
                exit(9);
        }
        printf("Finished\n");
}
```

**Listener output**

```
$ ./listen
Listening!
```

**netstat**

```
$ netstat -a -n | grep 4000
udp        0      0  127.0.0.1.4000         *.*
```

**Sender output**

```
$ ./send fish
Sending: fish
The udata buf can hold 65535 bytes
I have set up 4 bytes and it contains fish
Calling t_sndudata()...
Finished
```

Comment: You might have better luck with this question on Retrocomputing ;-)

Comment: Are sender and receiver both running on the same machine?

Comment: Yes the current goal is to send from one program to another on the same machine. As written, I believe I'm choosing a listen port of 4000 and a source port of 4001 for the UDP send but I can't tell if the second part is working yet.